# how to append Values in NSMutableArray in Text View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitextview

I have one array that has many name in self.this is my code :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"figo",@"messi",@"totti",@"ronaldo",@"pirlo", nil];
```

I want append this names in one TextView that any name to be in one line... but when run this app at last I see last name is in UITextView and another names was remove!!! please guide me about it.

this is my complete code :

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextView *text;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextView *text;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize text;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"figo",@"messi",@"totti",@"ronaldo",@"pirlo", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i=0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        NSString *a = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",a);
        [text setText:a];
    }
}
@end
```

I want this name append in UITextView and these names to be in one line....like this:

```
figo
messi
totti
ronaldo
pirlo
```

Comment: Do you want to added in only one line or each in New line ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try instead

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"figo",@"messi",@"totti",@"ronaldo",@"pirlo", nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [text setText:[array componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
}
```

or if you want them all in a line, separated by whatever character, you can just replace @"\n" and use yours. `@", "` would be ok, but also `@" "`

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"figo",@"messi",@"totti",@"ronaldo",@"pirlo", nil];
    for (NSString *str in array) {
        tvText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", tvText.text,str];
    }
```

Comment: To print in same line use following code..  tvText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", tvText.text,str];

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"figo",@"messi",@"totti",@"ronaldo",@"pirlo", nil];
    NSMutableString* theText = [NSMutableString new];
    for (NSString* line in array)
    {
    [theText appendFormat: @"%@\n", line];
    }


[text setText:theText];
```

just change the NSString to NSMutableString